# How to call javascript function from server side

Tags: .net

in my code im using script manager and tinymc...at the start it loads just fine,,,but when i click a btn as the page dosnt post back due to script manager and update panel....the result comes fine...but the tinymc editor does not load ,,,i can only see textarea

And when i manually want to call javascript at the end of the code this error occurs..

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed. Common causes for this error are when the response is modified by calls to Response.Write(), response filters, HttpModules, or server trace is enabled.
Details: Error parsing near 'alert("hello'.

i need help how to solve this issue

THankyou

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it looks like the alert call is the problem:

`'alert("hello'.`

You have a double quote in there, next to the 'h'. That could be the problem.

Comment: im using this at the end of my btnclik function,,.,,   Response.Write("<script>alert('helloworld')</script>");